# Можно ли зашифровать Node.js проект, что б заказчик, имеющий доступ к серверу, не просмотрел исходный код?

Tags: javascript, node.js, безопасность

Можно ли зашифровать Node.js проект, что б заказчик, имеющий доступ к серверу не просмотрел исходный код?

Comment: Не отдавайте проект заказчику пока он не оплатит все. Размещайте сервер на своём ПК (или хостинг) и пускай заказчик смотрит результат и тестит приложение. Когда он оплачивает - отдаете ему исходники. Все.

Comment: Нельзя. А зачем вам это надо?